# When a particular website is accessed via localhost it shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong"

Tags: laravel, localhost

I tried to import the source code in my computer and edit a particular website. I   add directory link at vhosting script and input this 
VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin local.idea.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/idea"
    ServerName local.idea.com

when I type localhost it shows
--> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

but, if I input localhost/gjalksgjalk
or localhost/"anycharacter"
the page shows up, but displays error 404,
but other links and pages are working normally.
If I try to open the homepage by clicking button indicated in the image it again display "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

note: But when I create new project in laravel or other project it works fine.
What seems to be lacking here?
Hope someone can provide ideas to solve this problem. Thanks

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJup4.jpg) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOYS5.jpg) [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jQRG.jpg)

Comment: provide us your controller an routes

Comment: go to handler and check what is error ?

Comment: update your post with the `php artisan route:list` output

Comment: @Mateus, sir can you be more specific, am a noob in this field, tnx

Comment: run the `php artisan route:list` command in your terminal, and add the result to your question.

Comment: @Mateus, I add results at image 3,what does it mean?

Comment: @Mateus, I run php artisan route:list, what will be the specific item that I have to look for, its too many. tnx

Comment: Look at the route that returns the 404 error response

Comment: I turn on app debug to true and this error appears: in Builder.php line 1023
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\idea2\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder.php', 1023, array('scope' => array(object(Campaign), 'scopeActive'), 'parameters' => array(object(Builder)), 'query' => object(Builder)))
at count(null) in Builder.php line 1023, what could be the possible fix? tnx

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing the code:

From:

```
$originalWhereCount = count($query->wheres);
```

To

```
$originalWhereCount = count((array)$query->wheres);
```

Another code that also works:

```
$originalWhereCount = is_null($query->wheres)
                    ? 0 : count($query->wheres);
```

Everything now works normally in this particular project.  Another developer from github said that the original line of code may have an issue with PhP 7.2